# How can I implement a search bar to filter a list of customers by name in an ASP.NET web application using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to implement a search bar in my ASP.NET web application using C#. I have a list of customer objects and I want to allow the user to search for a specific customer by name. How can I implement a search functionality that filters the list of customers based on the user's search query? Should I use LINQ or is there a better approach?

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchString)
{
    
    var customers = _context.Customers.ToList();

   
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        customers = customers.Where(c => c.Name.Contains(searchString)).ToList();
    }
    return View(customers);
}
```

Comment: what's the issue you are facing with the code you shared in the question? You should use `Where` LINQ method directly on `_context.Customers` so that the query execution happens on the database without retrieving all the customers in the application memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use LINQ to implement the search functionality that filters the list of customers based on the user's search query.
Here's an updated version of your code with some improvements:

```
    public ActionResult Index(string searchString)
{
    // Retrieve all customers from the database
    var customers = _context.Customers.ToList();

    // Filter customers by name if search query is provided
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        customers = customers
            .Where(c =>c.Name.IndexOf(searchString,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
            .ToList();
    }

    // Pass the filtered customers to the view
    return View(customers);
}
```